# Question about provisioning assistant

Tags: iphone, code-signing, provisioning

The provisioning assistant in Program Portal doesn't allow me to add dot for App ID(like com.company.app). I can only add App ID with com.company.appname in Program Portal without assistant. But that App ID doesn't show up in assistant, what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provisioning assistant tries to be overly helpful if you're used to doing the task by hand. In other words, you're expecting to enter "com.company.appname", but the assistant doesn't want that.  Instead, the assistant wants what it calls "AppID Description", with no periods ".", and the AppID will be generated from that.

Yes, it's confusing.  If you want "com.company.myappname", then you want to enter "myappname" when prompted for AppID Description, and the real AppID ("com.company.myappname") will be generated from that.

Frankly, I haven't found the provisioning assistant to be any more helpful than doing it the other way, and as you've found it's a bit confusing.

My only guess as to why your other AppIDs don't show in the assistant is that they use wildcards.  All of my non-wildcard IDs show, but none of the wildcards do.

Comment: "I haven't found the provisioning assistant to be any more helpful than doing it the other way"--I can't agree more.

Comment: the assistant has left me in a state where I don't know which way isup.  I paid my money ($600 for mac mini, 299 for iphone and $100 for dev license and all I have to show for it is an ulcer and lots of links to apple urls.  What a nightmare this process is.

Comment: It can be a nightmare the first time you do it.  The answer *is* in the Apple links, and if followed to the letter can get you going in my experience. After the first time, it should seem less daunting.